# SQUID proxy - open FTP

Tags: proxy, squid

How can I open other ports than HTTP and HTTPS using SQUID proxy? 
I have last version of squid running on Fedora 10 but I'm not able to open FTP port.

my **squid.conf**:

```
acl manager proto cache_object
acl localhost src 127.0.0.1/32 ::1
acl to_localhost dst 127.0.0.0/8 0.0.0.0/32 ::1

acl ftp proto FTP
acl ftp_port port 21
always_direct allow FTP

acl SSL_ports port 443 20 21 22
acl Safe_ports port 20      # ftp
acl Safe_ports port 21      # ftp
acl Safe_ports port 22      # sftp
acl Safe_ports port 80      # http
acl Safe_ports port 280     # http-mgmt
acl Safe_ports port 443     # https
acl Safe_ports port 1025-65535  # uregistred ports
acl CONNECT method CONNECT

http_access allow manager localhost
http_access deny manager

# USER privilegies (encoded in file passwd)
auth_param basic program /usr/lib/squid/ncsa_auth /etc/squid/passwd
acl AUTHUSERS proxy_auth REQUIRED

# BLACKLIST (in file denied.conf)
acl denied_domains dstdomain "/etc/squid/DNDdomains.conf"
acl denied_regex url_regex "/etc/squid/DNDregex.conf"
http_access deny denied_regex 
http_access deny denied_domains

http_access allow AUTHUSERS
http_access deny !Safe_ports
http_access deny CONNECT !SSL_ports
http_access allow ftp_port CONNECT
http_access allow ftp
http_access allow localhost
http_access deny all
#http_reply_access allow all
#http_access allow all

http_port 3128
hierarchy_stoplist cgi-bin ?
cache_dir ufs /var/spool/squid 10000 16 256
coredump_dir /var/spool/squid
refresh_pattern ^ftp:       1440    20% 10080
refresh_pattern -i (/cgi-bin/|\?) 0 0%  0
refresh_pattern .       0   20% 4320
```

What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE:**
http_access **aloow** ftp -> **allow** (replaced)

Answer (score 1):

A quick scan of this page 
http://nixcraft.com/linux-software/384-ftp-through-squid.html
it looks like you might be ok generally.. Since it mentions you need

```
acl ftp proto FTP
http_access allow ftp
```

But I see you made a spelling error or typo in your config file

```
http_access aloow ftp
```

Comment: Mein gott :) Thank you, barlop! But I think it's still not the solution, I'll try it tommorrow

Comment: Nothing, still doesn't work (squid restarted) :(